# Equality of De Bruijn-indexed variables in a GADT

Tags: haskell, dsl, gadt

I have a problem convincing the compiler that two De Bruijn-indexed variables are the same. I have the following deep embeddeding of a DSL, with the De Bruijn indexing code based on Manuel Chakravarty's [Converting a HOAS term GADT into a de Bruijn term GADT](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~chak/haskell/term-conv/):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Ix env t where
    ZeroIx ::             Ix (env, t) t
    SuccIx :: Ix env t -> Ix (env, s) t

-- | Heterogeneous equality for 'Ix'. Note, this only ensures that
-- the indices are equal as integers; it does not ensure that their
-- type environments are equal. (Though we do require that the types
-- of the values they're bound to to be the same, i.e. @(a ~ a)@.)
eqIx :: Ix l a -> Ix r a -> Bool
eqIx ZeroIx     ZeroIx     = True
eqIx (SuccIx m) (SuccIx n) = eqIx m n
eqIx _          _          = False

data Dist env e where
    Var        :: Ix env e -> Dist env e
    --- XXX: What should Let look like?
    ConcatMap  :: (a -> [b]) -> Dist env [a] -> Dist env [b]
    -- For sibling fusion:
    ConcatMap2 :: (a -> ([b], [c])) -> Dist env [a] -> Dist env ([b], [c])
    Fst        :: Dist env ([a], [b]) -> Dist env [a]
    Snd        :: Dist env ([a], [b]) -> Dist env [b]

fuse :: Dist env e1 -> Dist env e2 -> (Dist env e1, Dist env e2)
fuse (ConcatMap f v@(Var x)) (ConcatMap g (Var y))
    | eqIx x y = let e = ConcatMap2 (f `mapBoth` g) v
                 in (Fst e, Snd e)  -- XXX: Doesn't type check.
fuse e1 e2 = (e1, e2)

mapBoth :: (a -> [b]) -> (a -> [c]) -> a -> ([b], [c])
mapBoth = undefined
```

The function `fuse` tries to implement sibling fusion (a tupling optimization). I need to pattern match on two `Var`s that are the same. While I can compare the indices themselves, I also need to convince the compiler that the typing environment these indices are in is the same and they thus map to a value of the same type. I have a feeling that this might be solved by adding the `Let` constructor and pattern matching on it, but it's unclear to me how. Here's an abridged version of the type error:

```
/tmp/Minimal.hs:27:14:
    Could not deduce (a1 ~ a)
    from the context (e1 ~ [b])
      bound by a pattern with constructor
                 ConcatMap :: forall env a b.
                              (a -> [b]) -> Dist env [a] -> Dist env [b],
               in an equation for ‘fuse’
      at /tmp/Minimal.hs:26:7-27
    or from (e2 ~ [b1])
      bound by a pattern with constructor
                 ConcatMap :: forall env a b.
                              (a -> [b]) -> Dist env [a] -> Dist env [b],
               in an equation for ‘fuse’
      at /tmp/Minimal.hs:26:31-49
      ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
           a pattern with constructor
             ConcatMap :: forall env a b.
                          (a -> [b]) -> Dist env [a] -> Dist env [b],
           in an equation for ‘fuse’
           at /tmp/Minimal.hs:26:31
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          a pattern with constructor
            ConcatMap :: forall env a b.
                         (a -> [b]) -> Dist env [a] -> Dist env [b],
          in an equation for ‘fuse’
          at /tmp/Minimal.hs:26:7
    Expected type: Ix env [a]
      Actual type: Ix env [a1]
```

How can I pattern match on two variables that are the same?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can make your code type-check with two relatively simple changes. However I'm not entirely sure if they're truly valid in the wider context of your entire code.

Firstly, the type of `eqIx` doesn't make use of the knowledge you already have, namely that the `env` parameters are already known to be the same when you call it. We can change it to this instead and it'll still type-check - i.e. we assume that the environments are the same but the variable types may not be.

```
eqIx :: Ix env a -> Ix env b -> Bool
```

After this change, the important thing that `eqIx` does tell us is that the types of the two variables are actually the same. But by only returning a `Bool` we're hiding this from the compiler. If we instead return a standard type-level "equality witness", we can propagate this information:

```
data EqWitness a b where
    IsEq :: EqWitness a a

eqIx :: Ix env a -> Ix env b -> Maybe (EqWitness a b)
eqIx ZeroIx     ZeroIx     = Just IsEq
eqIx (SuccIx m) (SuccIx n) = eqIx m n
eqIx _          _          = Nothing
```

(There's probably some standard type for `EqWitness` on hackage somewhere)

Now we can add `PatternGuards` and change your call-site slightly to extract the equality witness when `eqIx` succeeds. This makes the equality available to the type-checker in the body of the relevant case:

```
fuse :: Dist env e1 -> Dist env e2 -> (Dist env e1, Dist env e2)
fuse (ConcatMap f v@(Var x)) (ConcatMap g (Var y))
    | Just IsEq <- eqIx x y
               = let e = ConcatMap2 (f `mapBoth` g) v
                 in (Fst e, Snd e)
fuse e1 e2 = (e1, e2)
```

Comment: To your "I'm not entirely sure if they're truly valid in the wider context of your entire code" comment, this seems a bit magical to me. How do we know that the two `Ix` belong to the same let? The same index might appear in several places, under different binders throughout the program.

Comment: Yes, that does seem like a concern. Would it have been any better with your original signature?

Comment: I honestly don't know.

Comment: `EqWitness` is `:~:` from [Data.Type.Equality](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Type-Equality.html), which is in base since 4.7.